# Link query strings get cut off

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, query-string

I'm not aware of link designing strategies, so I am not sure why my link gets chopped off when someone clicks on from sources like Facebook etc.

I have a 'share feature' on my platform, which lets a user create a link to their listing and share it with people.

The link I generate for the listing in my backend has parameters, which reads the listing id and the type and displays content over HTML

Here's a sample link for a listing

https://www.fayvors.com/Share.html?hash=5eccccaa-7b8d-42bd-af8c-08d50da0c867?type=lessons/

However, when I share the link on facebook and click it, the browser redirects to a link that's cut off

https://www.fayvors.com/Share.html?hash=5eccccaa-7b8d-42bd-af8c-08d50da0c867%3Ftype%3Dlessons

I'm not aware of link designing principles, so I'm a bit lost here!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your URL contains “special characters” (like a second question mark inside the query string), but you neglected to apply proper URL encoding when putting this URL as a parameter value into *another* URL:

> `javascript:window.location.replace('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+window.location)`

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the value you are concatenating to the sharer URL here.